# Say my name and I disappear

Tags: riddle

Here's a cute little riddle I heard in the movie Life is Beautiful.

> Say my name and I disappear. What am I?

Comment: You are "disappear" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Silence

I'm not sure how much explaining really needs to be done here. It's a classic riddle, and you can also hear it in variations like:

> What is so fragile it breaks when you speak of it?